# What does using ampersand (&) with minus operator achieve?

Tags: c, operators, ampersand

I'm preparing for a programming contest and I have stumbled upon the question below.

```
void main(){
    int number, result;
    scanf("%d",&number);
    result=number-(number&-number); //this is what i'm struggling to understand
    printf("%d",result);  
}
```

Note the use of "&-" in the commented line. I couldn't figure out its function. I tried googling and reverse engineering but I couldn't find anything.

Also, the question itself is not about the exact output because the variable "number" is dynamic. I just need to learn what the "&-" part do.
Thanks!

Comment: `number&-number` == `number & (-number)`

Comment: It's just an operator-think unary minus and take it from there.

Comment: This is achieving -10 into the karma of the author of this code.

Comment: isn't that logical AND (which is supposed to return binary results)? I am getting 4 when I put in 4.

Comment: No, its binary AND.

Comment: Isn't that taking the address of a temporary?

Comment: @DeiDei `-x` is not an lvalue.

Comment: @EugeneSh. A temporary is not an lvalue either, no? What I meant was, doing `&-x` causes undefined behavior. No?

Comment: @DeiDei What's "temporary", anyway? The address can be taken only for result of `*`, `[]` or an lvalue as defined [here](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.5.3.2p1)

Comment: In this context, `&` is the binary "and" operator. In other contexts, the same symbol is the unary address operator. Incidentally, `void main()` should be `int main(void)`. If you have a textbook that tells you to use `void main()`, its author doesn't know C well enough to be writing books about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ampersand is a binary AND operator. The minus is just a regular minus. Thanks to @tkausl

Answer (score 6):

This is a binary AND operator.  The expression `x & -x` zeroes out all but the rightmost 1-bit in the number x. Then `x - (x & -x)` zeroes only that bit, so the result is the original number with the rightmost 1-bit cleared.

Answer (score 0):

(number&-number)   means   (number & (-number))

Comment: Please provide a small description along with the code